# Outlook 2010 table spacing weirdness

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

When coding a HTML email newsletter Outlook 2010 is acting up. (surprise surprise)

The following screenshot is the result: http://screencast.com/t/PSZqP7wg
This screenshot shows what's happening (same, but images turned off): http://screencast.com/t/DrbexyHnytJ

Obviously, the middle white column is to narrow. Should be 604px wide, but is a lot less. It seems Outlook is placing extra padding next to the spacer images.

Anyone has an idea why this is happening?

This is the source in the body tag:

```
<table width="761" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" height="151" style="height: 151px;" style="padding: 0px;"><img width="761" height="151" src="http://www.bothino.be/newsletter/top.jpg" alt="" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="77" style="width: 77px;">
                <img src="http://www.bothino.be/newsletter/spacer.jpg" width="77" alt="" />
            </td>
            <td width="604" bgcolor="ffffff">
                test sdlkfjhklsdjfhqsdklfh qklsdfh klqsjf lqksjdf lkqsjdhf lkdflkqshdfkl jqhsdlkfj
                hqslkdfh qlksjdfh lqskjdhf lkqjshdlfk jqhsldkfh qlsdjfh lqksjdflk qsdflkqshdklfh
                klqshdf kqshdklf hqskldfqklsd
            </td>
            <td width="76" style="width: 76px;"><img src="http://www.bothino.be/newsletter/spacer.jpg" width="76" alt="" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="151" colspan="3">
                <img width="761" height="151" src="http://www.bothino.be/newsletter/bottom.jpg" alt="" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add a background color to both  tags. the widths are displaying correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm used to issues with "undefined" blank spaces and line breaks in IE and Outlook. They are usually interpreted as a real, wanted space, formatted by style of the nearest parent (if any).
That's why i prefer writing htm like this:

```
    <tr>
        <td height="151" colspan="3"><img 
           src="http://www.bothino.be/newsletter/bottom.jpg"
           width="761" height="151" alt="" /></td>
    </tr>
```

Line breaks inside a tag will make no difference at display time ... but apply a similar structure to the code.
The important part is *no blank* between TD and IMAGE tag.

Maybe, this doesn't explain and solve that huge indentions in your screenshot.

Comment: Sadly, It doesn't indeed. As you can see in the code, the table cells containing these indentations already are coded without spaces :( (had that experience too some years ago)

Answer (score 0):

sometimes it's better to leave out width for `td`'s eg leave out `width=77` and rest of width for all td's. that way it can expand automatically to fill the entire row. or you can also include a table withing that tr.

Answer (score 0):

my experience with Outlook is to never ever never ever use the rowspan and colspan attributes. This is guaranteed to cause trouble. Should a table cell require a different layout/width than the one above/below it, nest another  right into it with the correct layout. this way the overall basic grid stays intact. Not nice, but then again: outlook plays dirty and so will you (have to). All tables need to have cellpaddign=0 and cellspacing=0. This helps me to get over similar issues.